# Laplace transform of a stopping time for stochastic volatility models

Tags: pr.probability, mathematical-finance, laplace-transform, reference-request

Let $V_t$ be a solution of the SDE

$$dV_t=V_t(rdt+\sigma_t dW_t) $$

where $\sigma_t$ satisfies some other SDE 
$$d\sigma_t=\alpha(t,\sigma_t)dt+\beta(t,\sigma_t)dW^{\\ \prime}_t   $$
and $W_t$ and $W^{\\ \prime}_t $ are possibly correlated Brownian motions.

I'm interested in the Laplace transform $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\{aT}\\ )]$ of the stopping time
$$T:=\inf\{t>0 \\ : \\ V_t\le \overline V\\   \}.  $$

If $\sigma$ is a constant, both $V_t$ and $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\{aT}\\ )]$ are explicitly computable and everything is known.

> **Question:** What is known about $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\{aT}\\ )]$ in the
>   general case? Are there any
>   specifications of the coefficients
>   $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that allow an
>   explicit formula?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi,
Have you taken a look at papers about pricing Barrier Options under Stochastic Volatility Models in Mathematical Finance such as Heston Model, SABR, etc...